# Where to find the VBR on the /dev/sda1 partition?

Tags: linux, boot, hard-disk, boot-loader, mbr

I have one built-in hard disk `/dev/sda` which looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00042134

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   293048319   146523136   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       293050366   312580095     9764865    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       293050368   312580095     9764864   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Now I can easily find the MBR with `xxd /dev/sda | less`, it's located in the first sector. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector#Kinds_of_boot_sectors) the VBR must be in the first sector within the first bootable partition, in my case `/dev/sda1`. But in the first sector of `/dev/sda1` I only see zeroes when I do a `xxd /dev/sda1 | less`.

I actually thought to find binary code of GRUB in there, where could it be then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It is usually not installed there**. Most of the time, GRUB (stage 1) is installed in the MBR *only*, on Linux.

Although GRUB version 1 will always overflow a little in the 30 kB following the MBR (stage 1.5, i.e. filesystem drivers), with GRUB version 2, the code installed within the MBR can load some other and bigger code (stage 1.5) by raw reading any sectors from the disk (but will usually stick to GRUB 1 behavior -- that is, loading code from the 30 kB after MBR).

Those 30 kB are usually available non-partitionned "free" disk space, because for [historical reasons](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/Large-Disk-6.html#ss6.2) it is pretty rare for the first partition of a disk to start before sector 63, which leaves at least 512*62 = 31 kiB after MBR.

Then, it loads some files, usually from `/boot`, like the menu (`menu.lst` or `grub.cfg`), more filesystem drivers, etc. This is stage 2.

After that, is has enough to launch an OS.

**As for the VBR now**, it *is not commonly used on Linux partitions because it is not reliable enough*, but MS Windows usually installs one at the beginning of system (C:\) partitions. GRUB will just execute it if you want to start Windows. This process is called chainloading: a bootloader which launches another one. This also means that the filesystem used there *must* leave untouched the beginning of its partition, because it could overwrite the VBR otherwise! The amount of "untouched" space available depends on the filesystem, so there is no good guarantee: it could well be very small...

**About loading stage 1.5 from an "unusual" place**, as I said, GRUB 2 can load its stage 1.5 from any sector on the disk. It may be from a file, but this can be dangerous because the filesystem can decide to move that file to other sectors on the disk anytime (or even worse, fragment it!), and GRUB would need to update the new sector number in the MBR each time...

An interesting case is [GUID Partition Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (GPT). They are too big to ensure that enough space (30 kB) will always be available for stage 1.5. The recommended solution in that case is to use a dedicated "boot loader partition" (not a problem since GPT can support 128 partitions) that will not host a filesystem but GRUB's stage 1.5 data. This way, it shall not move anywere, and you can give it plenty of space.

**You should really read [wikipedia's GRUB article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#Boot_process)** where I got most of this information.

Comment: I just found out that apparently on sector 1 of `/dev/sda` - directly after the MBR - there is a copy of `/boot/grub/core.img` or `/boot/grub/diskboot.img`.

Comment: But how does GRUB have access to the filesystem in this stage?

Comment: @Ian I think you answered your own question.

Comment: @Ian The GRUB code within the MBR (stage 1) is very small (limited by the MBR size), but big enough to load some other code from the disk (stage 1.5 and/or 2), wich can then load modules, and the OS. It is [explained in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#Boot_process).

Comment: @Ian updated answer.

Comment: Especially interesting is what anyone is doing combining hacks like embedding  legacy vector/bootloaders into the partition table  and a modern format like GPT in the first place. The whole *boot loader partition* idea is utter nonsense - in that it is a terrible idea and not that your answer is in any way correct. Grub *should* have died at 1.9 like it was meant to - the v2 reboot only made it worse.

Comment: @mikeserv why is a dedicated boot loader partition nonsense, and how would you replace it then?

Comment: Well, it's nonsense in a GPT context because GPT usually goes part-and-parcel with an EFI firmware - and in *that* context a bootloader - which was initially designed and implemented only to work around kernel execution size limits of BIOS systems - is redundant because an EFI firmware mounts a filesystem at boot and executes a *pathed* executable. In a BIOS+GPT *(but why???)* context I guess it is necessary, if still confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Actually GRUB2 is not normally installed to a VBR.  It recommends against this practice.

It's something like there not being enough space there to bundle a filesystem module for /boot.  Historically, MBR disks give you 62 "reserved" sectors for such boot code.  (Because the first partition starts on a cylinder boundary.  Nowadays we ignore cylinders, but it's aligned to a whole megabyte instead, to support 4K sector drives, help with SSDs / RAID, etc.).  You don't get such good guarantees from the VBR.

The message GRUB2 gives you explains that VBR (partition) installs have to rely on saving the block numbers of modules such as a filesystem driver.  This is less reliable; it means grub *has* to be reinstalled when those module files are updated.

Comment: You don't "get a whole megabyte" because the first partition starts on a cylinder boundary, but *because starting partitions on sector 2048 (1 MB), or a multiple of 2048, permits to avoid all sort of partition/filesystem/raid alignment issues*, so it has become best practice. Most of the time, a cylinder is considered to be approx. 8 MB (but cylinder doesn't really mean something anymore nowadays, because we use [LBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing), not [CHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector)).

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "standard MBR disk". It is a *de facto* thing, because old MS-DOS [used to require](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/Large-Disk-6.html#ss6.2) that partitions start on "cylinder" boundaries. Linux doesn't care and you can create your partition wherever you want (even *before* sector 62). However, this *de facto* practice has become a default setting in Linux `fdisk` for a while, to ensure old [DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) compatibility.